# Darken css image background

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

The background behind the image without darkening the image.
Currently I have an html element like this

```
<div className='new-offers-item-favourite' />
```

The element has a linear-gradient and an image set to it:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url('http://res.cloudinary.com/wisdomabioye/image/upload/v1462961781/about_vbxvdi.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

which affects the actual image too making it `0.3` opaque when I need it solid white.

Is there a way to do so w/o wrapping the image to a `<div>`? Maybe an `:after` pseudo element. Wish there was a css way.

**Update 1.**
Tried this too. Same effect.

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/new-offers-tem-favourite.3c611ec2.svg');
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.5;
```

Comment: Why would this make the image itself have any opacity? That makes no sense.

Comment: The image inside was a white star one. When applied the rules it became grayer.

Comment: because you applied a black color ... apply a white color

Comment: Well of course it does, because you laid the semi-transparent gradient on top of it. Guess: You don’t want _multiple_ backgrounds, you just want to specify a background _color_ alongside with the image …? Well then do _that_.

Comment: Please see Update 1.

Comment: Of course same effect, because you are applying opacity to the whole element. Specify a background-color with an opacity factor, if you only want the background-color to be opaque …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution.

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/new-offers-item-favourite.3c611ec2.svg');
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

The credit goes to @misorude.